# Lamson in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

Do anybody has experience hosting an email application in Lamson in Google App Engine?
Is it possible? Is it easy? Works well? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Jörg, but I found there is no need to install a email framework in Google Apps Engine as there is a Python [mail API already built in](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html)

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience in using Lamson on GAE. However, one important difference between GAE and traditional LAMP hosting is the storage backend and since Lamson *already* has support for a dozen different storage backends, the interfaces should be well-defined and narrow, so that adding a GAE backend should be rather trivial. (More precisely, Lamson simply doesn't *care* about the storage backend.)